# Django admin action delete_selected to be the last option in the drop-down list

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to display the delete_selected action in the drop-down list in the admin screen as the last option just for one model.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work like this. Would be there a nicer way?

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    actions = ['soft_delete_selected', 'soft_undelete_selected']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
    
        action = actions['delete_selected']
        del actions['delete_selected']
        actions['delete_selected'] = action

        return actions
```